# CSS rookie not understanding grids and flex setup (Creating a wordle game for my friends)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was following a youtube tutorial on how to create your own Wordle game. In that video they follow the strict 5 letter words that Wordle plays by. I want my game to have words of length 4-7.

When I changed the length from 5 to varying my character boxes went vertical:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EyDe.png)

```js
// Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7OhcuZQ-q8
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let word = "dairy";
    impactleWord();
    createSquares();

    let guessedWords = [
        []
    ];

    let availableSpace = 1;


    let guessedWordCount = 0;

    const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keyboard-row button');

    function impactleWord() {
        let wordLibrary = [];
        let s = "impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense";
        wordLibrary = s.split(',');
        const d = new Date();
        let impactleDay = Math.round((d.getTime() / 1000 - 1648360800) / 86400);
        word = wordLibrary[impactleDay];
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--cols`, `'${word.length}'`);
        // window.alert(word); // TODO: Delete -> Debugging purposes only
    }

    function getCurrentWordArr() {
        const numberOfGuessedWords = guessedWords.length;
        return guessedWords[numberOfGuessedWords - 1];
    }

    function updateGuessedWords(letter) {
        const currentWordArr = getCurrentWordArr();
        if (currentWordArr && currentWordArr.length < word.length) {
            currentWordArr.push(letter);

            const availableSpaceEl = document.getElementById(String(availableSpace));
            availableSpace = availableSpace + 1;

            availableSpaceEl.textContent = letter;
        }
    }

    function getTileColor(letter, index) {
        const isCorrectLetter = word.includes(letter);

        if (!isCorrectLetter) {
            return "rgb(58, 58, 60)";
        }

        const letterInThatPosition = word.charAt(index);
        const isCorrectPosition = (letter === letterInThatPosition);

        if (isCorrectPosition) {
            return "rgb(83, 141, 78)";
        }

        return "rgb(181, 159, 59)";
    }

    function handleSubmitWord() {
        const currentWordArr = getCurrentWordArr();
        if (currentWordArr.length !== word.length) {
            window.alert("Word must be 5 letters");
        }

        const currWord = currentWordArr.join('');

        const firstLetterId = guessedWordCount * word.length + 1;
        const interval = 200;
        currentWordArr.forEach((letter, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const tileColor = getTileColor(letter, index);

                const letterId = firstLetterId + index;
                const letterEl = document.getElementById(letterId);
                letterEl.classList.add("animate__flipInX");
                letterEl.style = `background-color:${tileColor};border-color:${tileColor}`;
            }, interval * index);
        });

        guessedWordCount += 1;

        if (currWord === word) {
            window.alert("Great success!");
        }

        if (guessedWords.length === word.length + 1) {
            window.alert(`Game over! The word is ${word}.`);
        }

        guessedWords.push([]);
    }

    function createSquares() {
        const gameBoard = document.getElementById("board");

        for (let index = 0; index < word.length * (word.length + 1); index++) {
            let square = document.createElement("div");
            square.classList.add("square");
            square.classList.add("animate__animated");
            square.setAttribute("id", index + 1);
            gameBoard.appendChild(square);
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        keys[i].onclick = ({ target }) => {
            const letter = target.getAttribute("data-key");

            if (letter === 'enter') {
                handleSubmitWord();
                return;
            }
            updateGuessedWords(letter);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#game {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(58, 58, 60);
}

.title {
    color: gainsboro;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.4rem 0 0.4rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#board-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
    border: 2px solid rgb(58, 58, 60);
    min-width: 60px;
    min-height: 60px;
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: gainsboro;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#keyboard-container {
    height: 200px;
}

.keyboard-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 8px;
    touch-action: manipulation;
}

.keyboard-row button {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 58px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(129, 131, 132);
    color: rgb(215, 218, 220);
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    user-select: none;
}

.keyboard-row button.wide-button {
    flex-grow: 1.5;
}

.spacer-half {
    flex-grow: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Worlde For Friends</title>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="game">
            <header>
                <h1 class="title">Friendle</h1>
            </header>

            <div id="board-container">
                <div id="board"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="keyboard-container">
                <div class="keyboard-row">
                    <button data-key="q">q</button>
                    <button data-key="w">w</button>
                    <button data-key="e">e</button>
                    <button data-key="r">r</button>
                    <button data-key="t">t</button>
                    <button data-key="y">y</button>
                    <button data-key="u">u</button>
                    <button data-key="i">i</button>
                    <button data-key="o">o</button>
                    <button data-key="p">p</button>
                    <div class="spacer-half"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="keyboard-row">
                    <button data-key="a">a</button>
                    <button data-key="s">s</button>
                    <button data-key="d">d</button>
                    <button data-key="f">f</button>
                    <button data-key="g">g</button>
                    <button data-key="h">h</button>
                    <button data-key="j">j</button>
                    <button data-key="k">k</button>
                    <button data-key="l">l</button>
                    <div class="spacer-half"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="keyboard-row">
                    <button data-key="enter" class="wide-button">Enter</button>
                    <button data-key="z">z</button>
                    <button data-key="x">x</button>
                    <button data-key="c">c</button>
                    <button data-key="v">v</button>
                    <button data-key="b">b</button>
                    <button data-key="n">n</button>
                    <button data-key="m">m</button>
                    <button data-key="del" class="wide-button">Del</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any explanation as to what is going wrong with the spacing and grid is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the CSS variable --cols as 6 inside quotes.

It should be set without the quotes.

```
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--cols`, word.length);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Worlde For Friends</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: black;
      height: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    #game {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    header {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(58, 58, 60);
    }
    
    .title {
      color: gainsboro;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0.4rem 0 0.4rem 0;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #board-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #board {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
      grid-gap: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .square {
      border: 2px solid rgb(58, 58, 60);
      min-width: 60px;
      min-height: 60px;
      font-size: 44px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: gainsboro;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    #keyboard-container {
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .keyboard-row {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto 8px;
      touch-action: manipulation;
    }
    
    .keyboard-row button {
      font-family: inherit;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 58px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(129, 131, 132);
      color: rgb(215, 218, 220);
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-right: 6px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .keyboard-row button.wide-button {
      flex-grow: 1.5;
    }
    
    .spacer-half {
      flex-grow: 0.5;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    // Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7OhcuZQ-q8
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      let word = "dairy";
      impactleWord();
      createSquares();

      let guessedWords = [
        []
      ];

      let availableSpace = 1;


      let guessedWordCount = 0;

      const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keyboard-row button');

      function impactleWord() {
        let wordLibrary = [];
        let s = "impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense,impact,sample,four,fives,sixsix,sevense";
        wordLibrary = s.split(',');
        const d = new Date();
        let impactleDay = Math.round((d.getTime() / 1000 - 1648360800) / 86400);
        word = wordLibrary[impactleDay];
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--cols`, word.length);
        // window.alert(word); // TODO: Delete -> Debugging purposes only
      }

      function getCurrentWordArr() {
        const numberOfGuessedWords = guessedWords.length;
        return guessedWords[numberOfGuessedWords - 1];
      }

      function updateGuessedWords(letter) {
        const currentWordArr = getCurrentWordArr();
        if (currentWordArr && currentWordArr.length < word.length) {
          currentWordArr.push(letter);

          const availableSpaceEl = document.getElementById(String(availableSpace));
          availableSpace = availableSpace + 1;

          availableSpaceEl.textContent = letter;
        }
      }

      function getTileColor(letter, index) {
        const isCorrectLetter = word.includes(letter);

        if (!isCorrectLetter) {
          return "rgb(58, 58, 60)";
        }

        const letterInThatPosition = word.charAt(index);
        const isCorrectPosition = (letter === letterInThatPosition);

        if (isCorrectPosition) {
          return "rgb(83, 141, 78)";
        }

        return "rgb(181, 159, 59)";
      }

      function handleSubmitWord() {
        const currentWordArr = getCurrentWordArr();
        if (currentWordArr.length !== word.length) {
          window.alert("Word must be 5 letters");
        }

        const currWord = currentWordArr.join('');

        const firstLetterId = guessedWordCount * word.length + 1;
        const interval = 200;
        currentWordArr.forEach((letter, index) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            const tileColor = getTileColor(letter, index);

            const letterId = firstLetterId + index;
            const letterEl = document.getElementById(letterId);
            letterEl.classList.add("animate__flipInX");
            letterEl.style = `background-color:${tileColor};border-color:${tileColor}`;
          }, interval * index);
        });

        guessedWordCount += 1;

        if (currWord === word) {
          window.alert("Great success!");
        }

        if (guessedWords.length === word.length + 1) {
          window.alert(`Game over! The word is ${word}.`);
        }

        guessedWords.push([]);
      }

      function createSquares() {
        const gameBoard = document.getElementById("board");

        for (let index = 0; index < word.length * (word.length + 1); index++) {
          let square = document.createElement("div");
          square.classList.add("square");
          square.classList.add("animate__animated");
          square.setAttribute("id", index + 1);
          gameBoard.appendChild(square);
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        keys[i].onclick = ({
          target
        }) => {
          const letter = target.getAttribute("data-key");

          if (letter === 'enter') {
            handleSubmitWord();
            return;
          }
          updateGuessedWords(letter);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="game">
      <header>
        <h1 class="title">Friendle</h1>
      </header>

      <div id="board-container">
        <div id="board"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="keyboard-container">
        <div class="keyboard-row">
          <button data-key="q">q</button>
          <button data-key="w">w</button>
          <button data-key="e">e</button>
          <button data-key="r">r</button>
          <button data-key="t">t</button>
          <button data-key="y">y</button>
          <button data-key="u">u</button>
          <button data-key="i">i</button>
          <button data-key="o">o</button>
          <button data-key="p">p</button>
          <div class="spacer-half"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="keyboard-row">
          <button data-key="a">a</button>
          <button data-key="s">s</button>
          <button data-key="d">d</button>
          <button data-key="f">f</button>
          <button data-key="g">g</button>
          <button data-key="h">h</button>
          <button data-key="j">j</button>
          <button data-key="k">k</button>
          <button data-key="l">l</button>
          <div class="spacer-half"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="keyboard-row">
          <button data-key="enter" class="wide-button">Enter</button>
          <button data-key="z">z</button>
          <button data-key="x">x</button>
          <button data-key="c">c</button>
          <button data-key="v">v</button>
          <button data-key="b">b</button>
          <button data-key="n">n</button>
          <button data-key="m">m</button>
          <button data-key="del" class="wide-button">Del</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```